# Image carousel last image getting pushed to the right because of margins

Tags: javascript, css

I have a image slider that I want to implement into my site. Everything works just fine except that the last slide has a small part being cut off and if you press the button once more the slider goes 14px more to the right, and it looks kind of unprofessional.

It's a little hard to explain, but if you use it in the snippet you will understand what im referring to.

All of this is caused by a `margin-left: 14px;` that I have set on the images for them to not touch each other and create a bit of room.

So my question is if it would be possible to remove the little jump it does in the end of the slide but still keep the spacing between the images, it doesn't have to be a margin or 14px exactly just so they aren't touching.

I've tried to fiddle with margins on the last child but can't seem to get it to work, I also hav tried updating the JS to account for the last 14px on the last child but either my JS skills isn't enough or it just doesn't work.

I know the JS is accounting for the `margin: 14px;` in the scrolling function but without it the images don't scroll all the way. But that can be removed if the solution doesn't include the margin at all.

```js
const carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel"),
  firstImg = carousel.querySelectorAll("img")[0],
  arrowIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper i");
let isDragStart = false,
  isDragging = false,
  prevPageX,
  prevScrollLeft,
  positionDiff;
const showHideIcons = () => {
  // showing and hiding prev/next icon according to carousel scroll left value
  let scrollWidth = carousel.scrollWidth - carousel.clientWidth; // getting max scrollable width
  arrowIcons[0].style.display = carousel.scrollLeft == 0 ? "none" : "block";
  arrowIcons[1].style.display = carousel.scrollLeft == scrollWidth ? "none" : "block";
};
arrowIcons.forEach((icon) => {
  icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth + 14; // getting first img width & adding 14 margin value
    // if clicked icon is left, reduce width value from the carousel scroll left else add to it
    carousel.scrollLeft += icon.id == "left" ? -firstImgWidth : firstImgWidth;
    setTimeout(() => showHideIcons(), 60); // calling showHideIcons after 60ms
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 935px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper i {
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  color: #343f4f;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 44px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: transform 0.1s linear;
}
.wrapper i:active {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.9);
}
.wrapper i:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.wrapper i:first-child {
  left: -22px;
  display: none;
}
.wrapper i:last-child {
  right: -22px;
}
.wrapper .carousel {
  font-size: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.carousel img {
  height: 340px;
  object-fit: cover;
  user-select: none;
  margin-left: 14px;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
.carousel img:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .carousel img {
    width: calc(100% / 2);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .carousel img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
        <div class="wrapper">
          <i id="left" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
          <div class="carousel">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false" />
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aHVtYW58ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&w=1000&q=80" alt="img" draggable="false" />
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/14/13/23/ocean-3605547_1280.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false" />
          </div>
          <i id="right" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
        </div>
```

Comment: Really hard to spot what is supposed to be wrong, with how that snippet renders. (Dunno, maybe not using the same image for every slide would make it a bit clearer, because then we could actually see that something is happening ...?)

Comment: @CBroe I removed some pictures and used diffrent ones so now the only thing you see when clicking the button is the "problem" im referring to. (If you open it in full page its much easier to understand)

Comment: @DarkBee could you make a fast example on how you mean I should do this? Struggling a bit to understand what you are meaning.

Comment: The image width is calc(100%/3) so the images are a third of the container, plus the margin makes them get cut off. if you make the images smaller in width to compensate they will fit. e.g. `calc(100%/3 - 14px)`

Comment: @Brooklyn i've tried doing exactly that but that creates another problem of not scrolling the images as far as they need to and showing a small line of the next image on the side.

Comment: @DarkBee no that's not what i'm thinking about, its the small portion of the last image getting cut off because of the margin pushing it to the right. I've edited my snippet to show three different pictures so the only thing you see when scrolling is what i'm referring to.

Comment: Ok, keep in mind you are loosing 28px due to the margin not 14px: *((#items - 1) * margin)*

Comment: @DarkBee yes that's correct my bad, was this "((#items - 1) * margin)" something you think could solve something or just to show that the total margin lost is 28px?